# Whats the point of AWS EC2 volumes if you can't launch instance?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-storage, cloud-computing

I created a ubuntu instance from images available in EC2. It created EBS volume during this. I ran instance from it and then terminated it (to avoid charges for then I don't run it). *Now the volume is still there.* And a naive person like myself might assume that you just need to boot from the volume.

But it seems there is no way. You have to create a snapshot and something else.

I don't understand it at all. If there is no data saved on the volume - then what's purpose of a volume? If there is data - why can't I boot from it?

My task is simple. I want use free AWS rates by staying under the limit. To do so I have to terminate my instance after I done. I don't care for specific data. It's ok to load in the beginning and unload in the end. But it seems only half of story.

Can someone translate the aws crazy architecture in to few simple humane words?

I am sure I am not the only one with such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you terminate an instance the volume is deleted. If you stop an instance the volume is kept. You can enable termination protection on an instance that prevents termination, but that's easy to disable if you have appropriate rights in IAM.

In the [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) you get a t2.micro that can run for a full year without being turned off, 30GB of disk (EBS storage, inc SSD), an RDS database instance, 5GB of S3 standard storage, plus a lot more. One catch is I don't think EBS snapshot storage is included, so you may have to pay for snapshots.

There's no need to turn your instance off if you're not using it. You have enough credit to run that server 24/7 for 12 months.

I think in your question you have terminology confused. The terms like terminate are very specific. If you terminated an instance the disk isn't there, however if you took a snapshot or created an AMI they'd still be there.

AWS isn't for beginners who want a bit of hosting, it's a huge sprawling enterprize grade infrastructure platform. I spent two years studying AWS and getting their certifications, but with a bit of reading you should be able to understand the basics of compute (EC2) and storage (EBS/EFS/S3).

AWS provides excellent documentation on all its services, as well as tutorials and beginners guide. Just type what you want to learn into Google and you'll find a huge number of resources from AWS and others. If there's anything you can't work out after reading you can post a comment and I'll try to help.

If you want basic, use [AWS LightSail](https://amazonlightsail.com/) VMs.

**Update**

Something I just remembered. You can set up an instance so the volume isn't deleted on termination, using termination protection. Read the [documentation here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#preserving-volumes-on-termination). If you set this flag when you created the instance your volume will persist after the instance is deleted.

Comment: thanks Tim. I appreciate you took your time to explain me that I am too stupid to have rights asking questions. But yet you failed to answer the question - once I terminate the instance (with volume kept, *not* deleted) - what is the purpose of the volume? is there any data left on that volume or it is empty? but I guess you already said everything you wanted.

Comment: When you terminate an instance the associated volume is deleted, unless you set [delete on termination](DeleteOnTermination) to false when you started the instance. My best guess is you set that flag or you stopped the instance rather than terminating it. Are you sure you _terminated_ the instance, or did you simply _stop_ it? Did you set that flag? I suggest you go in and start two t2.nano on-demand instances (not spot), wait for them to show _running_status, then label or name the volumes so you know which is which. Stop one, terminate the other.

Comment: Also, problem did this cause? You don't want to get billed, but under the free tier you get 30GB of EBS storage and one t2.micro for a year. Unless you go over that amount you don't need to stop your instance when you're not using it.

Comment: Yes I used the "termination protection". this is why in the question I say - I still have the volume. The problem is that I don't understand what the volumes for. I like to know Tim. I that kind of person. Can you explain what volumes are good for if they don't keep data. Its like if hard drives would loose information if I power off my PC.. Yes I heard you first time. I can run the instance all year round. But I don't care. I want to know what I can do with the volumes. How they can be useful.. I don't know how else can I rephrase my question..

Comment: The data from your instance is saved on the volume. What you've done is is the equivalent of taking a hard drive out of a computer. The data is intact so you can either start another instance from that disk or mount the disk as a data disk to an instance. I think [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-launch-snapshot.html) shows how to use the volume to create an instance. [This page](http://www.n2ws.com/how-to-guides/connect-aws-ebs-volume-another-instance.html) shows how to mount as data volume. I only quickly reviewed pages, might not be right page.